# Codeigniter Image Manipulation Class : Resize and Crop on multiple files

Tags: php, image-manipulation, codeigniter-2

I'm struggling to get the CodeIgniter Image Manipulation working correctly. Either it's a bug or I'm just not seeing it. I hope someone can help me with it. Thanks in advance!

On the script: I want to create thumbnails (176w x 132h). The input images are in different sizes and ratios. In order to always get this size I first resize them to fit the max width or height (depending on image orientation) and then crop in the center.
I've tried to do it all in 1 method. That didn't work, so I created two seperate methods.

```
resize_img()
```

and

```
crop_img().
```

When I run resize_img() on 3 different files, it works. If after that I use crop_img() on these thumbnails the 1th method created, it works. If I combine the two, or use them after one another, it doesn't.
I've tried $this->image_lib->clear();, unsetting the config files. I even created two config files, just to be sure.

I'm getting different all kind of errors from GD2, but the problem is, that after resize_img() creates the thumbnail, the crop_img() won't crop it. After that it all goes south, and the next images can't be opened. Write premissions are checked, both on folder and files.

> Unable to save the image. Please make sure the image and file
>   directory are writable. The path to the image is not correct. Your
>   server does not support the GD function required to process this type
>   of image.

Full code:

```
<?PHP

class Imagetest extends MY_Controller {

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('image_lib');
}

function index()
{
    $testimg1 = 'uploads/test/1.png';
    $testimg2 = 'uploads/test/2.png';
    $testimg3 = 'uploads/test/3.png';

    $this->resize_img($testimg1);
    $this->crop_img($testimg1);

    $this->resize_img($testimg2);
    $this->crop_img($testimg2);

    $this->resize_img($testimg3);
    $this->crop_img($testimg3);
}


function image_thumb_name($img = null)
{
    if(!empty($img)) {
        $exploded = explode('.', $img);
        return $exploded['0'] . '_thumb.' . $exploded['1'];
    }
}

function get_axis($img)
{
    // Default values
    $output['x_axis'] = 0;
    $output['y_axis'] = 0;

    // Settings
    $config['height'] = 132;
    $config['width']  = 176;

    if ($img_dim = getimagesize($img)) {
        list($thumb_width, $thumb_height) = $img_dim;
    } else {
        echo '<h1> ERROR HERE TOO</h1>';
        return false;
    }

    if ($thumb_width > $config['width']) {

        $output['x_axis'] = (($thumb_width - $config['width']) / 2) ;               

    } else if ($thumb_height > $config['height']) {

        $output['y_axis'] = (($thumb_height - $config['height']) / 2);
    }       
    return $output;
} 

function resize_img($img) 
{
    $config = array();
    echo 'Processing: '. $img .'<br/>';  // Debug

    if ($img_dim = getimagesize($img)) {
        list($image_width, $image_height) = $img_dim;
    } else {
        echo '<h1> ERROR HERE </h1>';
    }

    // create a thumbnail
    $config['image_library'] = 'GD2';
    $config['source_image'] = $img;
    $config['quality'] = 100;
    $config['height'] = 132;
    $config['width'] = 176;
    $config['create_thumb']  = TRUE;
    $config['maintain_ratio']= TRUE;
    $config['master_dim'] = ($image_width > $image_height) ? 'height' : 'width';
    $this->image_lib->initialize($config);

    if (!$this->image_lib->resize()) { 
        echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
    }

    echo '<img src="../'.$this->image_thumb_name($img).'" /> <br/>'; // Debug

    $this->image_lib->clear();
    unset($config);
}   




function crop_img($img)
{
    $config2 = array();

    // Crop that thumbnail
    $config2['image_library'] = 'GD2';
    $config2['quality'] = 100;
    $config2['height'] = 132;
    $config2['width'] = 176;
    $config2['source_image']  = $this->image_thumb_name($img);
    $axis = $this->get_axis($config2['source_image']);
    $config2['x_axis'] = $axis['x_axis'];
    $config2['y_axis'] = $axis['y_axis'];
    $config2['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
    $config2['create_thumb'] = FALSE;
    $this->image_lib->initialize($config2);

    if (!$this->image_lib->crop()) { 
        echo $this->image_lib->display_errors(); 
    }

    echo '<img src="../'.$config2['source_image'].'" /> <br/>'; // Debug

    $this->image_lib->clear();
    unset($config2);
}

}
```

Comment: I'm still not able to get this working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it!
I've set the create_thumb option to FALSE, and used the new_image parameter in the resize_img method. The effect is the same, but the built-in create_tumb function is not being used. 
It's a bug IMHO, but it's working now :)

```
$config['create_thumb'] = FALSE;
$config['new_image'] = $this->image_thumb_name($img);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your $config['source_image']

```
var_dump($config['source_image']);
```

see what you get.

If the file is in images folder in root folder, the $config['source_image] = 'images/'.$img.

Also make sure all the exploding functions returning the correct file name. (return and echo to check).

1st, eliminate file not found error. After that, see what error comes.

Comment: itachi, thanks for looking into it. 
I've double checked the file names, they're correct.
The file not found error is because the 2nd method is trying to crop the thumbnail the 1th should create, but it didn't and therefore it does not exist.

ps.
When I run it like this:

    $this->resize_img($testimg1);
    $this->resize_img($testimg2);
    $this->resize_img($testimg3);

It does work, then I need to comment this part out, and do this. (also works).  

    $this->crop_img($testimg1);
    $this->crop_img($testimg2);
    $this->crop_img($testimg3);
The problem is, that it doesnt work together.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Kodem's [Image Resize Service](https://kodem.io/documentation/3?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=9015911&utm_campaign=imageresize). You can resize, crop any image with just a http call. Can be used casually in the browser or used in your production app.