# CodeIgniter Image Lib class doesn't resize image but returns true

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to resize an image using codeigniter's image lib library. Pretty simple. However, the image isn't resized and moreover, the function returns true, display_errors() doesn't show any errors.

Here's my config that I'm passing to the image lib:

```
    //A file is uploaded using codeigniter's upload library, then:

    $imgData = $this->upload->data();

    $config['image_library'] = 'GD';
    $config['source_image'] = $imgData['full_path'];
    $config['new_image']    = $imgData['full_path'];
    $config['create_thumb'] = false;
    $config['maintain_ratio'] = true;
    $config['width'] = $newWidth;
    $config['height'] = $newHeight;
```

A print_r of $config after its been set:

```
Array
(
    [image_library] => GD
    [source_image] => C:/wamp/www/uploads/8ddbfb2cce91ee314e1f296355aec8c6.jpg
    [new_image] => C:/wamp/www/uploads/8ddbfb2cce91ee314e1f296355aec8c6.jpg
    [create_thumb] => 
    [maintain_ratio] => 1
    [width] => 400
    [height] => 350
)
```

The paths are correct, however the image remains untouched after resizing.

Doing a `var_dump` on `$this->image_lib->display_errors()` returns this:

```
string '' (length=0)
```

If it makes any difference, the images are being uploaded through Uploadify.

Any ideas on what's wrong?

Comment: For those more interested in the process, there is a [video about it](https://vimeo.com/10951360).

Comment: What are the re-size commands you are issuing in the order you are issuing them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to set the full path from your document root and not from C.
Try this code:

```
if($this->upload->do_upload()){
    $this->load->library('image_lib');

    $config_res['source_image'] = 'uploads/'.$this->upload->file_name;
    $config_res['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
    $config_res['width'] = $newWidth;
    $config_res['height'] = $newHeight;


    $this->image_lib->initialize($config_res);

    $this->image_lib->resize();

    $this->image_lib->clear();
}
else{
     echo $this->upload->display_errors();
}
```

in this way you don't need to specify the new_image and it will be overwritten

Comment: No luck :(. `Array ( [image_library] => gd [source_image] => uploads/06a6dce4fdb9199101bdfa5435b71718.jpg [create_thumb] => [maintain_ratio] => 1 [width] => 400 [height] => 350 )`

Comment: Ugh, I wasn't passing $config to image_lib, using the initialize method that you gave fixed it, now it works! Bounty = awarded in 21 hours when it lets me

Answer (score 0):

Did you set `create_thumb` to an empty string? Looking at CodeIgniter source, setting this parameter to anything else than the boolean `FALSE` (which is the default value) is recognized as a value of "true".

The purpose of the create_thumb mode is to append a suffix to the name of the generated files, by default "_thumb". http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/image_lib.html

Maybe you have "filename_thumb.jpg" files in your uploads folder? If so, issue found ;) Just delete or fix your `create_thumb` parameter.

As a side note, `maintain_ratio = 1` doesn't work, only `TRUE` works.

Comment: No, they're both set to boolean values. `$config['create_thumb'] = false; $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;`

Answer (score 0):

Did You Try To Avoid This Bugs on the create_thumb function ?
& Boolean in Capital Letter?

```
$config['create_thumb'] = FALSE;
$config['new_image'] = $this->image_thumb_name($img);
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9040862/1444072

Answer (score -1):

make sure **Note: In order for the image class to be allowed to do any processing, the folder containing the imags.**e files must have write permissions.**

**Note: Image processing can require a considerable amount of server memory for some operations. If you are experiencing out of memory errors while processing images you may need to limit their maximum size, and/or adjust PHP memory limit

Comment: Yeah, its got permissions, files are being uploaded using ci as well and I'm on windows